# Cucumber: disable or delete local storage using Poltergeist (PhantomJS)

Tags: cucumber, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

Trying to disable or delete local storage for a Cucumber test.

I have tried the following:

```
page.driver.execute_script("localStorage.clear()")
```

but I receive the following error

```
 One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

  SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
  at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1 (Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError)
```

Comment: For reference here is the capybara-webkit ticket that Justin opened: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/582

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the very same error. The problem was that I was trying to execute a script without visiting a page first. This throws the error as explained by Justin above:

```ruby
shared_context '@user is logged in' do
  before do
    # visit '/'
    credentials = @user.create_new_auth_token
    token = credentials['access-token']
    page.execute_script "localStorage.setItem('token', '#{token}')"
  end
end
```

This works:

```ruby
shared_context '@user is logged in' do
  before do
    visit '/'
    credentials = @user.create_new_auth_token
    token = credentials['access-token']
    page.execute_script "localStorage.setItem('token', '#{token}')"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is this:

```
  visit '<the_url_needed>'
  page.execute_script('if (localStorage && localStorage.clear) localStorage.clear()')
```

Hope that helps.